# Which spam corpus I can use in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, spam-prevention, corpus

My question is fairly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248100/using-document-length-in-the-naive-bayes-classifier-of-nltk-python), but I decided to open another question thread. I hope it is fine.

I am building a spam filter using the NLTK in Python as well, but I've just started.

I am wondering which spam corpus I can use and how to import it? I have not found any 'built-in in the NLTK' spam corpora ([here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk_data/index.xml)).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [presentation](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cap5636/fall2011/nltk.pdf) uses the [enron-spam dataset](http://www.aueb.gr/users/ion/data/enron-spam/) (200,000+ emails).

> The training and testing sets come from a dataset of 200,000+ Enron
>   emails which contain both “spam” and “ham” emails

Comment: Thank you, that's a brilliant link! :)

Comment: I believe those are included in the TREC dataset. There was also some debate over the classifications. John Graham-Cumming did a follow-up study; perhaps you could obtain his data as well. I cannot quickly locate his final report but here's an interim pointer: http://blog.jgc.org/2006/05/theres-one-born-every-minute-spam-and.html Maybe his final publication was for CEAS 2006 or the 2007 MIT Spam Conference?

Comment: Thank you again :) The TREC dataset looks great as well, but their "Assumption of Risk" is a bit too much. It probably doesn't contain too sophisticated computer viruses, but I decided to go for the preprocessed Enron dataset. I can replace it later, if it's not big enough. The link is really interesting, I will definitely check if the classification spam/ham is reliable in Enron.

Comment: Brief update: The closest thing to a final report I have been able to find is the June 2006 Virus Bulletin article http://www.virusbtn.com/spambulletin/archive/2006/06/sb200606-spamorham (registration required).  It's not a final report, but it is probably the article I remember.  Maybe he never did publish a concluding report.

Comment: As for the "assumption of risk", as long as you take reasonable precautions (handle spam on a system which cannot send mail; use a mail reader where it's not even possible to do anything stupid if you double-click on attachments by mistake) you should be fairly safe .. but obviously, advice on SO should be taken with a grain of salt (-:

Answer (score 1):

Spam is not hard to obtain.  Reasonably fresh spam in large quantities is not necessarily a big challenge, either; the big conundrum is how to obtain ham.  If you are only building your own spam filter, of course, you can use your own ham.

The SpamAssassin Public Corpus is getting very old, but there you have it; http://spamassassin.apache.org/publiccorpus/

There is also the corpora from the TREC spam track, which are somewhat larger, but not much newer or less biased; http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~gvcormac/treccorpus/

Various enthusiasts continue to publish their spam on the web, but most fail to include full headers etc.  If you are only interested in "bag of words" filtering, maybe that's good enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the links. I'm implementing two spam filters to check if generative or discriminative classification works better for spam filtering task.